# Checking for an XML tag stored in a CLOB

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g

I need to check for the existence of an XML tag where the XML is stored as an CLOB.

I tried `existsNode`, but seem to get in trouble.

Just providing the jist of the XML that I am interested in (it's a big one):

```
<main requestType="create">
  <CATEGORY_ID>5</CATEGORY_ID>
  <NAME>Position Adhoc</NAME>
   <VIEW_CONFIG>
    <ViewConfig>
      <localization value="true"></localization>
      <DataSource dataFormat="XML" hasTotalRow="false" nodeDataFieldWidth="200" treeNodeDataField="0"></DataSource>
      <Ribbon>
        <Funds container="com.ssc.cfi.ribbon.fundbrowser.FundBrowser" enabled="true" entity="Portfolio" exclusiveGroup="" label="Portfolios" visible="true">
          **<List** enabled="true" fundFilterState="ACCT" label="Portfolio" maxSelectionAllowed="1000" showActiveCloseFunds="false" showManager="false"></List>
          <AllFunds enabled="true" entityName="AllFunds" showActiveCloseFunds="false"></AllFunds>
```

I need to find if the XML tag "List" exists anywhere in the XML. The XML data is stored as a clob in TAB_A in the column COL_A.

Tried this, but did not work and it gives me a count of 0 even though we can see the tag exists:

```
select count(1) 
from tab_a
where existsNode(extract(xmltype(col_a),'//main'),'//List') = 1
```

Any thoughts using either existsNode or xmlexists ?

Comment: Is <main> your root node? If so, why the extract then exists? Should just be existsNode(xmltype(col_a),'//List') = 1 I would think.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work although it seems logical !

Comment: Using your test example, both queries work for me.

Comment: what do you mean it didn't work. did existsnode return 0? if so is your real xml document using namespaces at all?

Comment: it did not work means "my result was 0" where I should expect 1 as there is the tag that i am checking for. But, its ok as it is working now...I dont know what the issue was earlier even though I did ot change a thing !